# How to paste texts into a list of files in python

Tags: python, file

Below is my file-list. Each file is opened in a writable mode and zipped with text. 
My goal is to transfer each text into the file it is zipped with.

```
file_list=[(<open file 'x', mode 'w' at 0x028F5758>, 'hi friend'), (<open file 'x', mode 'w' at 0x02943020>, 'whats your name?'), (<open file 'x', mode 'w' at 0x02943078>, 'you welcome')]
```

My attempt:

```
paste_texts=[x[0].write(x[1]) for x in file_list]
print [open('x', 'r').read() for x in paste_texts]
```

Output:

```
['', '', '']
```

I checked the files on my C drive and they were empty and untouched. Any suggestions on how to transfer each text into its adjacent file?

Comment: That first line is not valid Python.

Comment: You may need to `.close()` or `.flush()` your file objects in order for changes to be committed to disk.

Comment: Hi Senshin, I tried closing before posting but I got this error message:AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'close'

Comment: Did you do `x[0].write(x[1]).close()`? Because you can't do that. `.write()` returns `None`. You'll want to turn this into a loop rather than a list comprehension.

Comment: @TimPietzcker, you can't just say the first line is not valid without any suggestions or explanations, that's not write.

Comment: @Tiger1: Of course I can. If you had run this, you wouldn't have received the output you show, you would have got `SyntaxError`s. Obviously you haven't shown us your actual code. It doesn't make sense to try and answer a question where we're given misleading information.

Comment: Hi @TimPietzcker, I actually modified the opened files in the first line to simplify the question. You can't just run the code like that, you know open files don't look the way I presented them in the code, the basic idea is what the question depict.

Comment: Hi @TimPietzcker, I have now included the full file path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does not make sense to use a list comprehension for this.

Use a simple `for` loop:

```
file_names = 'hi_file.txt', 'name_file.txt', 'welcome_file.txt'
my_strings = 'hi friend', 'whats your name', 'you welcome'

for (text, fname) in zip(my_strings, file_names):
    with open(fname, 'w') as f:
        f.write(text)
```

---

*edit (see comments):*

```
for (text, f) in zip(my_strings, file_list):
    f.write(text)
```

Comment: Hi wim, the dataset is massive and it has been presented to me that way (files zipped with texts). I thought list comprehension is the best way to go.

Comment: Well what exactly is the input format because your example is not valid python code.  If it's a list of file handles zipped with strings, then just iterate through the list and do the write, the loop will be the same form as my answer.

Comment: the files are already opened, i just shorened them thats why the list appear like its not a valid code: [<open file 'x', mode 'w' at 0x02B730D0>, <open file 'x', mode 'w' at 0x02B73128>, <open file 'x', mode 'w' at 0x02B73180>]

Comment: hi wim, I got the following error when I used your proposed simple loop:TypeError: with open(fname, 'w') as f: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, file found

Comment: Then you don't need the `open` line anymore, because you already have open file handles.  See my edit.

Comment: yea, you are right, i had the files opened, I shouldn't have opened then again.

Comment: Hi @wim, the code works fine, but my files are still empty even after closing the files.

Comment: Who is closing the files?  Are you _sure_ they are being closed?  That's what `with` would have done for you automatically, if you weren't being given open file handles.  Honestly, the interface of being given a whole bunch of open file handles in the first place seems kinda strange.

Comment: Hi @wim, its now working, one of the list I was zipping with was actually a list of list, hence nothing was really written on the files. I had to de-list before getting to the actual text. Many thanks for your support.